# YUI Compressor and CSS content?

Tags: css, yui, yui-compressor, minify

I have a stylesheet with the following code:

```
.author-name:before {
 content:"by: ";
}
```

When I run this through YUI Compressor, I get:

```
.author-name:before{content:"by:"}
```

This is a problem because it wipes out intended whitespace. I thought using the YUI Compressor special comments, like this:

```
.author-name:before {
  /*!YUI-Compressor */content: "by: ";
}
```

... might help, but it seems not to. Additionally, the comments themselves got wiped out. My impression based on the was that comments in JavaScript that start with `/*!` [get preserved](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html), but that's not actually happening.

Short of post-processing my build process to unminify, is there a way to do this? We're currently using version 2.3.5 of YUI compressor, and running with the flags `--charset utf8 -v -o`

So my question, in short, is, is there a way to get YUI Compressor to respect spaces in `content:` values, or a way to add CSS comments before and after a block I don't want minified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, try using unicode entity instead of space character itself:

```
.author-name:before {content: "by:\00A0"; }
```

`\00A0` in particular is non-breaking space.

Comment: This is an okay workaround. I am still hoping for a YUI Compressor fix. How well is the `\00A0` syntax supported in browsers which support `content` for CSS `content`?

Comment: Perfectly supported across all major browsers including IE8+. Only inconsistency I've encountered is using compound literals like `"foo" "bar"` which has issues in IE as far as I remember, but here is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your css using version 2.3.4 and 2.4.6 and both preserve the space inside the string. So it's either a very specific bug (can't find anything in the bug tracker) or something else is going wrong. Are you sure it's a ascii space character and regular apostrophes (not the Windows smart ones or something)?

When I run a test on the same css replacing ascii quotes with unicode character 201C, a left double quotation mark, the space is removed. The reason is quite simple: the parser doesn't recognize it as a string and therefor it strips white space.

You might want to try the latest version from here http://yuilibrary.com/download/yuicompressor/ anyway. In case your current version is installed using some package manager: just extract the .jar file from the archives 'build' folder.

Comment: Thanks for checking. That's so strange that it behaves differently. I'm solving it with the escaped CSS strings, and that appears to meet my needs, but when we revisit tooling on this project I'll try the more current versions of YUI Compressor.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I'm quite certain it's standard space and quote characters in the CSS -- not Windows characters. And it's just thespace that gets stripped.

Comment: Added another test to clarify the remark about quotes and a case where spaces do get stripped.

Answer (score 1):

You might add a margin to the content:

```
.author-name:before {
    content: "by:";
    margin: 0 .35em 0 0;
}
```

Comment: .3em or even .35em is usually more close to space character width.

Comment: good point. it's always better to use the intended css properties for spacings instead of white spaces.

Comment: @apparat: margin is somewhat more flexible but not always best way. If we need exactly same width as space character has, using literal space can be a more appropriate option consistent across different fonts in particular.

Comment: This is an okay workaround. I am still hoping for a YUI Compressor fix.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: I would like to argue about the leading zero. I think my way is more readable.

Comment: @MaratTanalin: I agree, if you have to be super exact that's right. but most of the time this isn't needed.

Comment: @erenon Leading zero is fine syntactically (same as adding a unit in zero values like `0px`), but usually redundant, so it's established good practice to avoid it in real-world web-development. You are free to edit it back if you strongly wish though.